# Inconsistent AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am learning how to create heatmaps from CSV datasets using Pandas, Seaborn and Numpy.

```
# Canada Cases Year overview - Heatmap

# Read file and separate needed data subset
canada_df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/main/data/countries-aggregated.csv', usecols = [0, 1, 2], index_col = 0, parse_dates=[0])
canada_df.info()
canada_df.head()
```

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 110370 entries, 2020-01-22 to 2021-08-09
Data columns (total 2 columns):

| # | Column | Non-Null | count | Dtype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Country | 110370 | non-null | object |
| 1 | Confirmed | 110370 | non-null | int64 |

dtypes: int64(1), object(1)

|  | Country | Confirmed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Date** | Afghanistan | 0 |
| 2020-01-22 | Afghanistan | 0 |
| 2020-01-23 | Afghanistan | 0 |
| 2020-01-24 | Afghanistan | 0 |
| 2020-01-25 | Afghanistan | 0 |
| 2020-01-26 | Afghanistan | 0 |

```
#Filtering data for Canadian values only
canada_df.loc[canada_df['Country']=='Canada']

#Isolating needed subset
canada_cases = canada_df['Confirmed']
canada_cases.head()

# create a copy of the dataframe, and add columns for month and year
canada_heatmap = canada_cases.copy()
canada_heatmap['month'] = [i.month for i in canada_heatmap.index]
canada_heatmap['year'] = [i.year for i in canada_heatmap.index]

# group by month and year, get the average
canada_heatmap = canada_heatmap.groupby(['month', 'year']).mean()
```

At this point I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-787f01af1859> in <module>
      2 canada_heatmap = canada_cases.copy()
      3 canada_heatmap['month'] = [i.month for i in canada_heatmap.index]
----> 4 canada_heatmap['year'] = [i.year for i in canada_heatmap.index]
      5 # group by month and year, get the average
      6 canada_heatmap = canada_heatmap.groupby(['month', 'year']).mean()

<ipython-input-54-787f01af1859> in <listcomp>(.0)
      2 canada_heatmap = canada_cases.copy()
      3 canada_heatmap['month'] = [i.month for i in canada_heatmap.index]
----> 4 canada_heatmap['year'] = [i.year for i in canada_heatmap.index]
      5 # group by month and year, get the average
      6 canada_heatmap = canada_heatmap.groupby(['month', 'year']).mean()

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'year'
```

I'm stuck on how to solve this, as the line above is pretty much the same but doesn't raise the same issue. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your error.

Here

```py
canada_cases = canada_df['Confirmed']
```

you're extracting one column of the dataset and it becomes a `Series` object, not `Dataframe`. Which then carries over to `canada_heatmap`.

```py
type(canada_heatmap)
>>> pandas.core.series.Series
```

As such, using an assignment with

```py
canada_heatmap['month'] = ANYTHING
```

creates a **new record** in the series with the index value "month", **not a new column**.

Thus, on the first pass `canada_heatmap.index` is still a `DatetimeIndex` and has `.year` or `.month` attribute, but it breaks in the next line, as now the index is just strings. And strings don't have `.year` attributes.

---

Instead do:

```py
import pandas as pd

covid_all_countries = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/main/data/countries-aggregated.csv', usecols = [0, 1, 2], index_col = 0, parse_dates=[0])
covid_canada_confirmed = covid_all_countries.loc[covid_all_countries['Country']=='Canada']
canada_heatmap = covid_canada_confirmed.copy()
canada_heatmap.drop(columns='Country', inplace=True)
canada_heatmap['month'] = canada_heatmap.index.month
canada_heatmap['year'] = canada_heatmap.index.year
```

Note, that the last two statements are equivalent to what you were trying to achieve but without looping through all the values (even if using list comprehension). This is clearer, more concise and considerably faster.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for a thorough response! This code works and your explanation is incredible.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your indexes are not in a date format (2 elements are string, which are the two lasts elements)

```
# check the type of the elements in index
count = pd.Series(canada_heatmap.index).apply(type).value_counts()
print(count)

<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>    110370
<class 'str'>                                              2
Name: Date, dtype: int64

# remove them
canada_heatmap = canada_heatmap.iloc[:-2]
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple comments:

1. This line does nothing:

```py
#Filtering data for Canadian values only
canada_df.loc[canada_df['Country']=='Canada']
```

You need to assign the filtering to a value like this:

```py
#Filtering data for Canadian values only
canada_df_filt = canada_df.loc[canada_df['Country']=='Canada'].copy()
```

2. Next, try to set the month/year of `canada_df` before filtering it as a series like this:

```py
canada_heatmap = canada_df_filt.copy()
canada_heatmap['month'] = [i.month for i in canada_heatmap.index]
canada_heatmap['year'] = [i.year for i in canada_heatmap.index]
```

This works on my machine.

Comment: Right, I completely forgot about assigning the filtered value to a new argument. Thank you!